# ClassNotFoundException for a test class in Eclipse maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, testng

I create the simplest maven project in eclipse. I add one JUnit test in src/test/java. Then I create a simple application (in src/main/java) that tries to do `Class.forName("package.MyTestClass");`. The class is not found even though the eclipse project is defined to export the `src/test/java` as a source folder.

What is going on? How can I fix this?

I wanted to do the following with TestNG

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    // Class.forName("package.MyTestClass");
    TestNG.main(new String[]{"testng.xml"});
}
```

It fails because it cannot find the test classes with:

> [TestNG] [ERROR]  Cannot find class in classpath: package.MyTestClass

Comment: can you also paste your MyTestClass.And kind of surprising how maven let you create a "package.*".It usually is com.abc.abc right?

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood you correctly, your project is like this

```
/src/main/java/Main.java (or whatever you have called it)
/src/test/java/package/MyTest.java
```

In your `Main` class you are trying to create an instance of a test class. This will not work. The classes in your `main` directory are available to the classes in your `test` directory, not the other way around, which makes sense. Your test classes must know about your application to test it, but your application should not know about the test classes